# Import ambiguity for PermissionStatus in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, location, user-permissions

I have to dynamically check for location permission in my Flutter appliaction,
For that I am using below plugins:

```
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
location: ^4.4.0
```

Now, Its needed to check for the permission status i.e. granted, denied, restricted and allowed. So, for that I am declaring PermissionStatus as below:

```
PermissionStatus locationPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied;
```

But due to below two imports one is for location and one is for permission,

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

It saying me on PermissionStatus declaration:

> The name 'PermissionStatus' is defined in the libraries 'package:location_platform_interface/location_platform_interface.dart (via package:location/location.dart)' and 'package:permission_handler_platform_interface/permission_handler_platform_interface.dart (via package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart)'. (Documentation)  Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

How can I resolve this ambiguity of imported data from two different plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for import both packages.

```
import 'package:location/location.dart' as location;
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

for use location Permission.

```
location.PermissionStatus locationPermissionStatus = location.PermissionStatus.denied;
```

**I Hope this will solve your issue.**

Comment: Ohkay this make sense :)

Comment: if it is work for you then i think you can accept this answer.
Thank You. :)